# System.InvalidOperationException thrown when running as part of a WPF application. Xabe.FFmpeg

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I have the following code which runs on a console application

```cs
  string filePath = "C:\\Users\\**\\Desktop\\sample-mp4-file.mp4";
  string output1 = "C:\\Users\\**\\Desktop\\1.jpg";
  string output2 = "C:\\Users\\**\\Desktop\\2.jpg";
  var ms = new MultiSnapshotCommand(filePath);
  await ms.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), output1);
  await ms.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), output2);
  await ms.Invoke();
```

Which uses the following

```cs
  public async Task Add(TimeSpan timestamp, string outputPath)
  {
      var conversion = await FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.Snapshot(filePath, outputPath, timestamp);
      conversionQueue.Enqueue(conversion);
  }
```

This executes fine and both snapshots are created when calling `Invoke()`.
However, when executing the same code running in an async method in response to a button click in a WPF scenario, the UI freezes, then a few moments later `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Diagnostics.Process.dll` is shown from the debugger output with no recovery.

The error seems to be occurring at `await FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.Snapshot(filePath, outputPath, timestamp);`

Original - https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/issues/341

### Edit

My project files https://github.com/Scharps/MP4ToImageConverter/tree/05beeb1cc359b654fb51a9695b5c20386c4d5fb6.
FFmpeg is required in Path system variable. File locations will need to be changed also

Comment: a sample project to reproduce the issue would raise the odds for getting an answer

Comment: @Mertus I have added my current project to the problem description, thank you.